# How to vectorize calculation of barycentric coordinates in python

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, vectorization, delaunay

In scipy.spatial there is the Delaunay function. The documentation includes an [example of how to calculate barycentric coordinates.](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.13.0/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.Delaunay.html)

Following that example, the following code will calculate barycentric coordinates using a loop.

```py
points = np.array([(0,0),(0,1),(1,0),(1,1)])
samples = np.array([(0.5,0.5),(0,0),(0.1,0.1)])

dim    = len(points[0])               # determine the dimension of the samples
simp   = Delaunay(points)             # create simplexes for the defined points
s      = simp.find_simplex(samples)   # for each sample, find corresponding simplex for each sample
b0      = np.zeros((len(samples),dim)) # reserve space for each barycentric coordinate
for ii in range(len(samples)):
    b0[ii,:] = simp.transform[s[ii],:dim].dot((samples[ii] - simp.transform[s[ii],dim]).transpose())
coord = np.c_[b0, 1 - b0.sum(axis=1)]
```

This is ok for short list of samples to convert to barycentric coordinates, however for very large lists of samples, the performance is poor. How can this be modified to take advantage of vectorized math in numpy/scipy to improve performance?

Answer (score 4):

Consider the following modification (for-loop replaced with numpy methods):

```
def f_1(points, samples):
    """ original """

    dim = len(points[0])
    simp = ssp.Delaunay(points)
    s = simp.find_simplex(samples)
    b0 = np.zeros((len(samples), dim))

    for ii in range(len(samples)):
        b0[ii, :] = simp.transform[s[ii], :dim].dot(
            (samples[ii] - simp.transform[s[ii], dim]).transpose())
    coord = np.c_[b0, 1 - b0.sum(axis=1)]

    return coord

def f_2(points, samples):
    """ modified """

    simp = ssp.Delaunay(points)
    s = simp.find_simplex(samples)

    b0 = (simp.transform[s, :points.shape[1]].transpose([1, 0, 2]) *
          (samples - simp.transform[s, points.shape[1]])).sum(axis=2).T
    coord = np.c_[b0, 1 - b0.sum(axis=1)]

    return coord
```

Test case:

```
N = 100
points = np.array(list(itertools.product(range(N), repeat=2)))
samples = np.random.rand(100_000, 2) * N
```

Result:

```
%timeit f_1(points, samples)
712 ms ± 2.76 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%timeit f_2(points, samples)
422 ms ± 809 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

With modified version the line `simp.find_simplex(samples)` gives about 95% of the running time. So, I guess there is nothing else you can do with vectorization. To improve perfomance further you need another implementation of `find_simplex` method or another approach to the problem.

Comment: You might also want to look into https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/41024/faster-computation-of-barycentric-coordinates-for-many-points